# How to classify observations based on their covariates in dataframe and numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataset with n observations and say 2 variables X1 and X2. I am trying to classify each observation based on a set of conditions on their (X1, X2) values. For example, the dataset looks like

```
df:
Index     X1    X2
1         0.2   0.8
2         0.6   0.2
3         0.2   0.1
4         0.9   0.3
```

and the groups are defined by

- Group 1: X1<0.5 & X2>=0.5
- Group 2: X1>=0.5 & X2>=0.5
- Group 3: X1<0.5 & X2<0.5
- Group 4: X1>=0.5 & X2<0.5

I'd like to generate the following dataframe.

```
expected result:
Index     X1    X2    Group
1         0.2   0.8   1
2         0.6   0.2   4
3         0.2   0.1   3
4         0.9   0.3   4
```

Also, would it be better/faster to work with numpy arrays for this type of problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your last question, I definitely think `pandas` is a good tool for this; it could be done in `numpy`, but pandas is arguably more intuitive when working with dataframes, and fast enough for most applications. `pandas` and `numpy` also play really nicely together. For instance, in your case, you can use `numpy.select` to build your `pandas` column:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Lay out your conditions
conditions =  [((df.X1 < 0.5) & (df.X2>=0.5)),
               ((df.X1>=0.5) & (df.X2>=0.5)),
               ((df.X1<0.5) & (df.X2<0.5)),
               ((df.X1>=0.5) & (df.X2<0.5))]

# Name the resulting groups (in the same order as the conditions)
choicelist = [1,2,3,4]

df['group']= np.select(conditions, choicelist, default=-1)

# Above, I've the default to -1, but change as you see fit
# if none of your conditions are met, then it that row would be classified as -1

>>> df
   Index   X1   X2  group
0      1  0.2  0.8      1
1      2  0.6  0.2      4
2      3  0.2  0.1      3
3      4  0.9  0.3      4
```

Answer (score 1):

Something Like

```
df[['X1','X2']].gt(0.5).astype(str).sum(1).map({'FalseTrue':1,'TrueFalse':4,'FalseFalse':3,'TrueTrue':2})
Out[56]: 
0    1
1    4
2    3
3    4
dtype: int64
```